# How to prevent a control inside a ControlTemplate from being resized?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize, controltemplate

Sorry in advance as I had trouble trying to think of the best way to convey my issue in a way that isn't too vague in the title but will be a little easier to understand as I explain the context.

Basically I have a re-sizable box that's composed of Thumb controls with a textblock above it that labels the associated box detailing of what it is.

The problem here is that as I resize it, the textblock also gets resized as well but only happens when I'm resizing the width of the box. The same doesn't happen when I resize the box by the height but my goal is to have it not be resized at all.

[Preview of resizing action](https://i.gyazo.com/d40b82643b93198a091cee034ef45cb5.gif)

I understand that since the textblock is grouped with the resizing control inside the control template that it makes sense for it along with other sibling controls to be affected by the resize as well but I don't understand why it only works specifically when the width of the item is affected.

My goal here is to find a way to make the labels not be affected at all by the resize action but to stay with the associated box at the same time (in the event the user decides to say move the box to a different position)

Here's the code for the control template:

```
<!-- Designer Item Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid x:Name="DesignerGrid" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <s:MoveThumb x:Name="MoveThumbAdorner" Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/>
            <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="rectCP" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
            <Border x:Name="BoxLabelBorder" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,-35" Background="#EEEEEE" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3">
                <Grid x:Name="BoxLabelGrid" Margin="5">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="BoxLabelStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DelClassBtn" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="15" MinWidth="15" Width="15" Click="DelClassBtn_Click">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d6d6d6"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#bebebe"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".35"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="7" Width="7" Source="/Resources/Images/cross_48.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: just define your height and width statically with a numeric value

Comment: @DenisSchaf i tried setting both for the textblock but it doesn't change anything. also the reason why I don't want a static width is because the textblock should stretch based on the length of the text inside

Comment: so you want the textbox to stretch but not to stretch? Logic like this need to be implemented in code and can't be done in XAML. You can set the MinWidth of the control to prevent it from getting smaller that the value.
but then the window can still be made so small that your control disappears partially so you would have to set the MinWidth of the parent as well and repeat that all the way up to your window

Comment: @DenisSchaf the textblock should stretch to fit its contents when it's loaded as well as if the text changes by user interaction (therefore ruling out the use of minwidth). However it should not be changed when its sibling control (the contentpresenter "rectCP" is resized). Now yes, if i somehow bind the control's minwidth to match the textblock's current width it would prevent this issue, but that isn't a viable solution because of necessary use cases in regards to that. My guess so far that it may have to do with how its positioned layer-wise